# Passing env values to Gradle tasks in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, gradle-plugin, vscode-java

I need to pass a env value to a gradle task. In shell I just prepend the env value:

```
ENV_VAR=VALUE gradle dockerBuildImage
```

How can I do this in the gradle plugin in VSCode? I can only see the "Run Task with Args" when I right click in the task... and that allows me to add things like "--info" but not to prepend an ENV value.

(I have already tried the Run configurations... but I am not willing to run the project, just to execute specific Gradle task that require env values... i.e. a token value not included in the project resource configuraton files)